# How to see modules that depend on a given module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vue.js, package.json

we can see all dependencies modules of a given moudle,like this:

`npm-remote-ls <module-name>`

but How to see modules that depend on a given module?

thank you in advance.

Comment: You can check the "Dependents" tab in npmjs site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue

Comment: there is no such a command. You should do what yuriy636 said

Comment: @yuriy636  thank you. there is any more efficient way to do that? If it has many dependents,this way is so Inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  npm view <PACKAGE> dependencies
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such command. You can check the `Dependents` tab on [npm.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and cross reference it with the packages you have installed.